# Communication between sibling directives inside isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to let one child directive to tell its sibling some information has been updated.

I have this markup:

```
  <rp-nav>
     <rp-nav-item cat="1"></rp-nav-item>
     <rp-nav-item cat="2"></rp-nav-item>
     <rp-nav-item cat="3"></rp-nav-item>

     <rp-flyout></rp-flyout>
  </rp-nav>

  <hr>

  <rp-nav>
    <rp-nav-item cat="one"></rp-nav-item>
    <rp-nav-item cat="two"></rp-nav-item>
    <rp-nav-item cat="three"></rp-nav-item>

    <rp-flyout></rp-flyout>
  </rp-nav>
```

I am using events in this way:

```
angular.module('rpNavItem', [])
  .directive('rpNavItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope) {},
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: true,
        // scope: true,
        template: function(el, attrs) {
          return  '<div>Item ' + attrs.cat + '</div>';
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            el.on('click', function(){
                scope.$broadcast('selectedCat', attrs.cat);
            });
        }
    };
});

angular.module('rpFlyout', []).directive('rpFlyout', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    // scope:true,
    controller: function($scope) {},
    template: '<p style="background-color: lightblue">{{category}}</p>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.$on('selectedCat', function(event, value){
        scope.category = value;
        scope.$digest();
        console.log(value);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The problem is that every time I click on one item, both flyouts get update and I just want the corresponding one updated. How can I achieve this?
Is this the correct way to pass information between two sibling directives confined inside a parent isolated scope?

### [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SzvA5vjqdim14Ma3HuYE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every isolate scope is child of the same `$rootScope` so you cannot use the events to separate directives. `$broadcast`-ed events are used for global (up to the root) communication.

To communicate directly with directives you can use the `require` property of directives, so `rpNavItem` can require `rpNav` and use `rpNav` to share state.

`rpFlyout` is not needed for this example, javascript:

```
angular.module('app', ['rpNav']);

angular.module('rpNav', [])
    .directive('rpNav', function() {
        return {
            scope: true,
            controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
              this.setSelectedCat = function (cat) {
                $scope.category = cat;
              }
            }]
        };
    });

angular.module('rpNav')
    .directive('rpNavItem', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
              cat: '@'
            },
            template: function (el, attrs) {
              return  '<div>Item ' + attrs.cat + '</div>';
            },
            require: '^rpNav',
            link: function (scope, el, attrs, rpNav) {
                el.on('click', function(){
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                      rpNav.setSelectedCat(scope.cat);
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

The HTML can become something like:

```
<div rp-nav>
  <rp-nav-item cat="1"></rp-nav-item>
  <rp-nav-item cat="2"></rp-nav-item>
  <rp-nav-item cat="3"></rp-nav-item>

  <p style="background-color: lightblue">{{category}}</p>
</div>

<hr>

<div rp-nav>
  <rp-nav-item cat="one"></rp-nav-item>
  <rp-nav-item cat="two"></rp-nav-item>
  <rp-nav-item cat="three"></rp-nav-item>

  <p style="background-color: lightblue">{{category}}</p>
</div>
```

If you wish to keep `rpFlyout` directive for some reason you can make it have isolated storage too and pass the current category in an attribute (untested code):

```
<rp-flyout category="category"></rp-flyout>
```

Directive:

```
[...]
.directive('rpFlyout', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
              'category': '='
            },
            template: '<p style="background-color: lightblue">{{category}}</p>'
        };
    });
```